# Notion of distance between linear programs

Tags: linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, linear-programming

Consider the linear programming problem
\begin{align}
\max_{x}&~c^Tx \\~s.t.~~a^Tx &\leq B~,~0\leq x_i \le1
\end{align}
where $c$ and $a$ are $n \times 1$ given non-negative vectors. $B$ is a positive constant (call it "Budget Constraint") and $x_i$'s are required to be in the interval $[0,1]$ (call it "Box Constraint"). Assume that the problem is always feasible. This is the mathematical formulation of an engineering problem we are trying to solve. Typically $n$ runs into tens of thousands for our problem. Let the dual variable corresponding to Budget Constraint be $\lambda$ and the dual variables ($n$ of them) corresponding to Box constraints be $\alpha_i$. What is important for us is the nature of $\lambda$ itself. Now, consider a slightly noisy version of the above LP problem
\begin{align}
\max_{x,\tilde{x}}&~c^Tx + \tilde{c}^T\tilde{x} \\~s.t.~~a^Tx + \tilde{a}^T\tilde{x}&\leq B~,~0\leq x_i \le1~,~0\leq \tilde{x}_i \le1
\end{align}
where $\tilde{c}$ and $\tilde{a}$ are non-negative $m \times 1$ vectors. Typically $m <<n$ and is often in hundreds. Let $\lambda_n$ denote the corresponding dual variable for Budget Constraint. In practice, we have often observed that $\lambda$ is close to $\lambda_n$. Intuitively, the problems seems to be close to each other depending on the nature of the additional terms.

Is there some literature which studies the notion of distance between such linear programs? We could only find literature that studies LP problems with noisy versions of $c$ and $a$ and not in terms of a number of variables. Our actual problem is a combination of both where the dimensionality, as well as the co-efficents, are noisy. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not consider the first LP as one with an expanded number of variables $\{x,\tilde{x}\}$ and setting some coefficients appropriately to zero? And then the second LP can be studied in the light of perturbation analysis of the first LP. Hope I got your question right.

Comment: @DSM Can you please point to references like that?

Comment: What I mentioned is just an extension of the variable space (so that the two LPs in your question are comparable), and the usual ideas in LP. You might want to look any standard references (Bertsimas) for perturbation/sensitivity analysis. As far as 'distance between LPs' is concerned, I have not come across such an idea.

Comment: @DSM most of such references assume that a small noise is added to a set of coefficients whereas in my case, they are literally zeroed out. Also, let's say $m$ is a random variable in itself, only very small in its values compared to $n$. Thus, the count of additional terms that can appear is randomized. Thus, I am not interested in a fixed $n + m$ which then reduces to $n$ variable LP via perturbation. I am interested in set of all LPs with $n+m$ variables and any notion of distance of them to the $n$ variable LP.

Comment: Okay. I think I did not note the random perturbation in the number of variables.